# Integral $\int_0^4 \int_\sqrt{y}^2 y^2 {e}^{x^7} \operatorname d\!x \operatorname d\!y\,$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I have to evaluate this integral:

$$
\int_0^4 \int_\sqrt{y}^2 y^2 {e}^{x^7} \operatorname d\!x \operatorname d\!y\,
$$

I have no idea what to do with $\;{e}^{x^7}$.

I have even [tried $\int{e}^{x^7} dx$ with WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int+e%5Ex%5E7+dx), but it gives me something with $\;\Gamma\;$ and I don't know what to do with that.

I tried posing $\;u = x^7\;$ and doing another change of variables. I got $\;445 {e}^{128}/9408\;$, but I'm not really sure about it.

If anyone could at least point me in the right direction, it would be awesome! Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The interchange of the order of integration is justified by Fubini's theorem:

$$
\int_0^4 \int_\sqrt{y}^2 y^2 {e}^{x^7} dxdy=\int_0^2\int_0^{x^2}y^2 {e}^{x^7} dydx=\frac 1 3\int_0^2 x^6{e}^{x^7} dx=\frac1{21}{e}^{x^7} \bigg|_0^2=\frac {{e}^{2^7}-1}{21} 
$$

Comment: That's pretty close to $\;445 {e}^{128}/9408\;$ when you evaluate them. Does this mean anything?

Comment: yes: if your result is not $=$ to it, it must be wrong ;)

Comment: Ha! Yeah, that's a good point.

Comment: I just did it; I got it! Thanks a lot!

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 5):

Change the order of integration; this leads to

$$\int_0^2 \int_0^{x^2} y^2 e^{x^7} dy dx = \frac 1 3\int_0^2 x^6 e^{x^7} dx$$

which is an easy integral.